# Simple integration with assumption

Tags: numerical-integration

I would like to evaluate the following simple expression

```
NIntegrate[Re[Exp[I*Omega*t]], {t, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

for `Omega` real, but mathematica does not evaluate it, neither by using `Integrate`. For `Omega` real it is simply the integral of`Cos[Omega*t]`. How can I specify mathematica that `Omega` is real so that it evaluates the integral?

Comment: You have good responses re `Integrate`. As for `NIntegrate`. I cannot imagine what numerical result one might hope to obtain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `ComplexExpand`

```
Integrate[ComplexExpand[Re[Exp[I*Omega*t]]], {t, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

> Sin[2*Omega*Pi]/Omega

Answer (score 3):

```
Integrate[Cos[a t], {t, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

or the somewhat messy:

```
Integrate[
 Simplify[Re[ExpToTrig[Exp[I a t]]], 
  Assumptions -> {a \[Element] Reals, t \[Element] Reals}], {t, 0, 
  2 Pi}]
```

=>`Sin[2 a \[Pi]]/a`